# Variable naming in combination of minimum and set builder notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I wonder if this notation is 100% correct, or whether it could be misunderstood in any way:

$m = \min \left\{ m \in \mathbb{N} \;\middle|\; f(m) > 0 \right\}$

In my opinion, the expression of the set $\left\{ m \in \mathbb{N} \;\middle|\; f(m) > 0 \right\}$ reduces (is that the correct term?) the variable $m$, so I am free to use it again in the assignment.

Comment: Yes; the "set builder" notation $\{ x \mid \ \  \}$ acts as a quantifier; thus the variable $x$ inside is bounded.

Answer (score 4):

There's no ambiguity, it's OK to write:

$m = \min \left\{ m \in \mathbb{N} \;\middle|\; f(m) > 0 \right\}$

But it could be confusing, may look like a typo.
So I would just rename the variable inside to something else e.g.

$m = \min \left\{ n \in \mathbb{N} \;\middle|\; f(n) > 0 \right\}$

This still means the same but avoids any confusions and doubts.